# Cursor moves slightly during trackpad click

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, dell-xps

I've noticed this on a few laptops, but this question is specifically for the Dell XPS 13 with the precision touchpad. Often if I attempt to click using the trackpad, the cursor will move slightly during the click. This causes the cursor to select the wrong item. It only seems to move about 10 pixels or less, but it's often enough to cause a click at the wrong location. Is there a setting to fix this, or to change the sensitivity? I do not have this problem on my current laptop with Synaptics drivers.

Comment: Did you find solution? I Have the same problem (yoga 720)

Comment: @PiotrBiałek Not yet unfortunately. I’m hoping an answer spontaneously appears someday for laptops in general, but I’ve noticed that the XPS 13 no longer seems to have this problem, at least with the ones I’ve tried

Comment: It is hard to tell because it is a difficult problem to reproduce. I think the problem is with windows 10. We need to wait for updates. Strange is that the problem is from at least 8 months and microsoft has done nothing about it.

Comment: It's so insane. I have had 4 laptops with precision drivers now (including a Macbook) and they all have this issue. Makes Windows barely usable and lets me even distrust pointer precision on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that Microsoft has provided any controls to tune that kind of behavior.
Looking at some images, it looks like that touchpad is a "clickpad" meaning you "click" by pressing the whole touchpad down, which sounds like the issue you are having.
A possible workaround is to use a different finger to click, than the one you are using to move the cursor.  Generally, you can press with a second finger and it doesn't change the effect of the first finger, and even keep the extra finger resting over the button area.
It is probably most intuitive to press in the lower left touchpad area (southwest) for left ie primary click, and in the right (southeast) for right ie secondary cick, but generally, any click that is not southeast will result in primary click.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs even while tapping to click.  If the cursor is not moved beyond the length of the error's displacement, the displacement will repeat on each consecutive tap in an identical manner.  This issue affects every Windows 10 system utilizing Precision Touchpad / Bootcamp drivers, regardless of Touchpad / Trackpad model.  The cursor will shift slightly to the right upon click.  A cycle can then be initiated by moving the cursor only directly back to the point of origin and clicking again, causing the displacement to occur repetitively.  At this time, no known workaround exists.